# Always display Add to Cart in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a product page here: http://www.noliftpalletmover.com/order/

I would like to always show Add to Cart rather than having it appear on hover. I have tried some CSS fixes but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet `http://www.noliftpalletmover.com/wp-content/themes/konstruct/assets/css/style.css?ver=1.1.1` at line number 6421, position of add to cart button (class name `.woocommerce .products li .add_to_cart_button, .woocommerce-page .products li .add_to_cart_button`) is set to "absolute". Remove "position", "left", "right" and "z-index" from that class declaration. And comment out class declaration at line number 6165 which as `transform: translateY`. That should do the trick for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin like [Simple Custom CSS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/) to add the following CSS to your site:

```
.woocommerce .products li .add_to_cart_button, .woocommerce-page .products li .add_to_cart_button {
    position: inherit !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 15px !important;
}
```

If this answers your question please mark it as the answer :)